# unable to update entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update records in existing table.  But nothing is getting updated.  It just silently goes through `db.SaveChanges()`.  synched is still false and practiceID is still null.  Please help.

```
var schedules = db.Schedules
    .Where(s => response.SucceededEhrAppointmentIDList.Contains(s.sche_id.ToString()))
    .ToList();

foreach (Schedule schedule in schedules)
{                  
    schedule.synched = true;
    schedule.PortalPracticeID = practiceID;
}
db.SaveChanges();
return "Success!";
```

UPDATE

It is updating the PortalPracticeID correctly but not the synched column.  synched is defined as a bit not null default value(0) column in my database.  I am not sure why i am not able to update synched to 1.

UPDATE 2

Just realized I have an update trigger on schedule table for another purpose that updates the synched flag to 0 whenever an update happens on Schedule table.  It is working as expected once I disable that trigger.  Thanks for help everyone.  @Sohaty db.database.log is something new I learned, thank you.

Comment: SaveChanges() returns the number of records it things were affected.  What does it return in your case?  How many `schedule` were in `schedules`?

Comment: for number of records i get 4.

Comment: you shouldn't need to attach at all, should you? if you just got it from the `db` it should already be attached

Comment: Explicitly attaching and setting the state shouldn't be necessary. Maybe that messes something up?

Comment: If SaveChanges() says it made 4 updates, I would believe it.  Are you sure you're looking in the correct database to check for the changes?

Comment: @DLeh yeah i removed that attach line.  i was trying different ways and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @Eric J - yes, i am looking in the correct database.

Comment: And remove this line. `db.Entry(schedule).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` It is unnecessary.

Comment: Check schedules.Count. Is it 4?

Comment: yes, schedules.Count is 4

Comment: Ok, try to assign delegate to db.Database.Log and log to text file all sql commands, which EF executes on DB.

Comment: user3817538, Why not add more code so we can help you?

Comment: @Sohaty - here is the log

Comment: UPDATE [dbo].[Schedule]
SET [synched] = @0
WHERE ([sche_id] = @1)
SELECT [Duration]
FROM [dbo].[Schedule]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [sche_id] = @1
-- @0: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
-- @1: '51781' (Type = Int32)

Comment: i am just showing only one update otherwise i can fit everything in this post.

Comment: Are you using a local database (MDF) ? If so, make sure it's pointing to the correct one in your connection string. I've seen that problem often.

Comment: is there way to change that db.Schedules.Where(..) query to fluent syntax like from s in db.Schedules ...........  I think thats where the problem might be.

Comment: You meant linq query, but I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just guessing, when you do a ToList() aren't you retrieving a copy (a different reference, you could use the GetHashCode() method to see if is equal) from the original source?

Try to do the foreach to the IEnumerable result from the where clause.

Comment: If I do it without ToList().  I get IQueryable instead.  Same thing happens, nothing gets updated.